# TypeScript Variable Undefined inside array.forEach()

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I will try to explain my problem. I have an array of a particular object and, from this array, I want to create a new one with the value of a particular field of each object.

In order to achieve this, I tried to use array.forEach() method but I get a variable undefined error inside the forEach() function. This is my code:

```
var values: number[];
measures.forEach((measure)=>{
    values.push(measure.value);
});
```

I've tried to declare the array values as public (and access this.values) and also to declare it in the function where I make the forEach and neither way worked.

Here is the error I get in the browser (angular CLI reports no problem):

```
ERROR TypeError: "values is undefined"
```

Comment: You must initialize the array: `let values: number[] = [];`.

Comment: You need to initialize the values array, not just define. Try values: number[] = []; instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to initialize your array rather than just declare it as

```
values: number[] = [];
```

You do not need the `var` keyword in angular if you are declaring a variable directly inside a component class. If you need to do it inside a function, use `let` keyword. more information **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)**

Comment: I do need the var keyword If I create my array inside a function.

Comment: then use `let`, not `var` @nlopez